# Remove remote file using Git Bash

Tags: git, command-line

I am using Git bash with PHPFog. On my local machine I deleted a PHP file using Windows explorer and I want to delete that same file from the server, maybe I created an out of sync problem with the server, not sure.

But having said this how do I delete the file from the server?

Below is the connection string to the remote server:

```
git@git01.phpfog.com:MY_HOST_GOES_HERE.phpfogapp.com
```

Comment: I meant to using the CLI Git Bash Here

Answer (score 4):

You're going to want to use something like the following:

```
git rm --cached file_name_here.php (or other extension)
git commit -m "Removed [filename] for [reason]"
git push
```

That'll completely remove it from your repository that's on the remote server.

Comment: Well, you probably should also commit and push for it to be on the server.

Comment: That did not work see: Welcome to Git (version 1.7.11-preview20120620)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.

Jim@JIMF /c/xampp/htdocs/phpfog (master)
$ git rm --cached g2.php
fatal: pathspec 'g2.php' did not match any files

Jim@JIMF /c/xampp/htdocs/phpfog (master)
$ 

Also when I browse to this file g2.php it is still on the server.